# How to send serialized data over a TCP connection in java

Tags: java, exception, serialization, tcp, datainputstream

I want to send data which i have serialized over a TCP connection.
I have created a client/server connection and am sending an Object after serializing it.
However, I dont know how should i read the data.

here is the code snippet:

### SENDING FUNCTION:

```
sendTo(String receiverAddr, int receiverPort,....., Object data) {
.
.
.
  if (data != null) { 
    byte[] byteObj = programming5.io.Serializer.serializeBytes(data);
    output.writeInt(byteObj.length);
    output.write(byteObj, 0, byteObj.length);
    output.flush();
  }
  output.close();
  sock.close();
}
```

### Function Call:

```
String hostname = somevalue;
int portNo = somevalue;
Hashtable <Integer, Integer> object = somevalue;

sendTo(hostname,portNo,...,object);
```

### Receiving Function:

```
DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

int length = input.readInt();
byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
input.readFully(bytes);

Hashtable<Integer, Integer> recvObj = (Hashtable<Integer,Integer)programming5.io.Serializer.deserialize(bytes);
```

This is not working. I am getting the following exception:

invalid stream header: 07F8ACED
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 07F8ACED

Please tell me how should i go about this.

Comment: Please tell us the data type of `output` variable in the first fragment

Comment: what do programming5.io.Serializer.serializeBytes and deserialize look like?

Comment: Yeah, looks like your are using a non-standard library. Google shows only one mentioning of this Serializer class which is not really helpful, certainly not enough to really able to help you here.

Comment: @Alexander:DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ObjectOutputStream` to write objects and `ObjectInputStream` to read them.